# URL transfer to another URL .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I don't know .htaccess well. I wanted to do something like this. When a user will go to this link:

```
www.example.ca/C2767442
```

I want to redirect them to

```
www.example.ca/index.php?searchtext=C2767442&action=searchresults
```

I have tried like below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^a-z0-9-])$  index.php?searchtext=$1&action=searchresults  [NC,L]
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably this (I haven't tested though):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$  index.php?searchtext=$1&action=searchresults  [NC,L]
```

1. You forgot to add uppercased characters
2. The ^ in the [] means: "match everything BESIDES character classess in the brackets.

Comment: +1 but make it: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?searchtext=$1&action=searchresults [NC,L,QSA]`